# Need to configure ASP.NET MVC routes with same constraints

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need the route to be like:

`http://localhost/{productName}/{featureName}`

where `productName = productId + URL friendly product name`, e.g. 1-some-product-name and `featureName = featureId + URL friendly feature name`, e.g. 1-some-feature-name

In order to achieve that I wrote the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ConcreteFeatureRoute",
            url: "{productName}/{featureName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Feature", action = "FeatureDetails" },
            constraints: new { productName = @"\d+?-[^/]*", featureName = @"\d+?-[^/]*" }
        );
```

But in a result I get `System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.`

How could I achieve that with route config?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post that which method throws this exception? You can also try to setup a [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to help to solve your problem.

Comment: also debug with Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/)

Comment: now I know what was my mistake, so the question is, how shouldI write the route config values to get that address in url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use one static keyword to find the specified url